# Pandas: When can we get a TypeError doing agg

Tags: python, pandas

This is a rather generic question: I would like to know in what cases `df.groupby(level = 'id').agg(['count'])` can result in the following type error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-b422fc0967b1> in <module>()
----> 4 df.groupby(level = 'id', sort = False).agg(['count'])

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in aggregate(self, func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
   2798         if hasattr(func_or_funcs, '__iter__'):
   2799             ret = self._aggregate_multiple_funcs(func_or_funcs,
-> 2800                                                  (_level or 0) + 1)
   2801         else:
   2802             cyfunc = self._is_cython_func(func_or_funcs)

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg, _level)
   2867             # reset the cache so that we
   2868             # only include the named selection
-> 2869             if name in self._selected_obj:
   2870                 obj = copy.copy(obj)
   2871                 obj._reset_cache()

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __contains__(self, key)
    905     def __contains__(self, key):
    906         """True if the key is in the info axis"""
--> 907         return key in self._info_axis
    908 
    909     @property

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in __contains__(self, key)
   1326         hash(key)
   1327         try:
-> 1328             self.get_loc(key)
   1329             return True
   1330         except LookupError:

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   1964 
   1965         if not isinstance(key, tuple):
-> 1966             loc = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=0)
   1967             return _maybe_to_slice(loc)
   1968 

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in _get_level_indexer(self, key, level, indexer)
   2227         else:
   2228 
-> 2229             loc = level_index.get_loc(key)
   2230             if isinstance(loc, slice):
   2231                 return loc

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2391             key = _values_from_object(key)
   2392             try:
-> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:
   2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:4881)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index._bin_search (pandas/_libs/index.c:8637)()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

I'm asking this because I have a dataframe where this error occurs in some cases but not always, for example if I use `df.head(n).groupby(level = 'id').agg(['count'])` then depending on n I get this error. For example it runs ok for head up to 2523475 and fails from 2523476 but I can't find anything wrong with the rows at those positions, they look the same as all the other rows in the dataframe and there are no null values.

I figure there must be something wrong with the data but in order to find what I need to know when this error can happen.

The data is a series in this format:

```
id       date      
3531364  2017-04-13    1
1550725  2017-02-21    1
1819411  2017-04-19    1
1636629  2016-12-28    1
3123152  2017-05-03    1
dtype: int64
```

In case it matters the dates are periods. Converting `to_dict()` gives me this:

```
{(1550725, Period('2017-02-21', 'D')): 1,
 (1636629, Period('2016-12-28', 'D')): 1,
 (1819411, Period('2017-04-19', 'D')): 1,
 (3123152, Period('2017-05-03', 'D')): 1,
 (3531364, Period('2017-04-13', 'D')): 1}
```

Some extra bits that might help somebody diagnose the problem:

Once I get the error if I do a `aux = df.head(5)` and then `aux.groupby(level = 'id').agg(['count'])` it fails BUT `aux.groupby(level = 'id').count()` works fine. This is also puzzling because with the original dataframe `df.head(5).groupby(level = 'id').agg(['count'])` works perfectly. Maybe something is cached? How can this happen?

If you try it with the Series I pasted here it will work for you and it will work for me but if I get the error and then get the `head(5)` of the `df` then it fails... (!). I guess eventually something is making `agg(['count'])` fail and that something is in some way cached by pandas but I really don't know what is going on under the hood.

I would appreciate any help with this. I know it is not easy.

Comment: So really what you want to know is why this error happens? Or am I mis-reading this?

Comment: Yes, why this error happens would help!